# Causal inference using regression for multiple covariates

Tags: regression, causality, treatment-effect

I am reading lot of material regarding Causal Inference using Regression Analysis but I am unable to resolve my doubt.

Suppose I have a data with Outcome ***Y***, Treatment ***Tr*** and covariates ***X1, X2, X3, X4, ....***

I need to find Average Treatment Effect using Regression Analysis for my data. with three model.

**First** with only outcome and treatment

```
model1-> lm(Y~Tr, data)
```

**Second** with outcome, treatment, and covariates

```
model2-> lm(Y~Tr+X1+X2+X3+X4+...., data)
```

**Third** with outcome, treatment, covariates and Interaction between covariates and treatment

```
model3-> lm(Y~Tr+X1+X2+X3+X4+....+X1*Tr + X2*Tr + X3*Tr + X4*Tr +......, data)
```

**I know for `model1` Average treatment effect(ATE) is coefficient of Tr in the `model1`.
For `model2` I think ATE is still coefficient of Tr in the `model2`. But I am not sure.
I am really confused what will be the ATE in our third model i.e. `model3`**

Comment: For model3 you would have to integrate over all covariates, aka marginalise. (That's what package **effects** does internally.) If the covariates are uncorrelated with treatment, model1 should give you the same answer.

Comment: @Carsten What about model2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the model 3 ATE will be the following

```
ATE =  beta0 + beta1*X1 + beta2*X2 + beta3*X3 + beta4*X4 + ...........
```

Answer (score 1):

For model 2, the coefficient on `Tr` does correspond to the ATE. For model 3, `Tr` is the ATE only when each covariate is centered at its mean. This straightforward for continuous variables, but for binary variables or interactions it can be tough to do this in an `lm()` statement.

To get the ATE, you can use the `margins()` function in the `margins` package. You can run

```
summary(margins(model3, variables = "Tr"))
```

to get the estimate and standard error of the ATE.

Comment: Can you explain more on why this is the case when mean-centering? Some kind of reference? I need to understand this better.

Comment: A reference is [Schafer and Kang (2008)](https://doi.org/10.1037/a0014268). This is because in linear models, marginal effects at the mean are equal to average marginal effects.